# UI5 sap.m.Table itemPress event

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.Table and I m trying to get the row information.

Here is my view.xml Table declaration:

```
<Table xmlns="sap.m" id="potiemsTable" inset="false" mode="MultiSelect" itemPress="rowSelectionChanged" >
```

And in the Controller I tried everything...But still no luck...

```
rowSelectionChanged: function(oControlEvent)
{
    var selectedRowContext = oControlEvent.getParameter("items"); 
    var link = oControlEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();
    var fr = oControlEvent.getBindingContext();
    var ctx = oControlEvent.getBindingContext();
    sap.m.alert(selectedRowContext);
},
```

The table uses bindAggregation to retrieve the rows through the provided OData service.

```
oTable.bindItems("/purchaseOrderSet(1)/purchaseItems",template);
```

Can someone tell me how to retrieve the context information of the clicked row?

Cheers!

Georgios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the [API documentation of `itemPress` event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.ListBase#events/itemPress):

> Fires when an item is pressed unless the item's `type` property is `Inactive`.

Please make it sure your ColumnListItems do have the type property rather than `Inactive` since `Inactive` is default value.

Answer (score 1):

Set the type property of the ColumnListItem

```
<ColumnListItem type="Navigation>...</ColumnListItem>
```