# SAPUI5/FIORI - SmartTable pressItem Event not triggered

Tags: jquery, xml, sapui5, sap-web-ide

i am trying to attach the itemPress event for SmartTable control in sap UI5. The view is defined in XML and bind to OData.

```
<mvc:View
   controllerName="myapp.controller.App"
 ...>
   <App>
      <pages>
         <Page title="title">
            <content>
                <smartTable:SmartTable
                    id="kubas"
                    ...
                    tableType="ResponsiveTable" 
                    ...>
                </smartTable:SmartTable>
            </content>
         </Page>
      </pages>
   </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Since for the ResponsiveTable the table behind is sap.m.Table i was trying to attach the itemPress event in the onAfterRendering event of controller. It did not work. Then i tried to override the onAfterRendering of the table itself and there attach the event - same effect, the event did not trigger.

```
onAfterRendering : function(){
            var tTable = this.byId("kubas");
            var oTable = this.byId("kubas").getTable(); //sap.m.table

            console.log(oTable.getMetadata().getName());

            oTable.setMode(sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelectMaster);

            oTable.onAfterRendering = function(){

                console.log("OnAfterRendering");

                this.attachItemPress(function(oEvent){
                    console.log("Pressed!!");
                });

            }
```

Do i do something wrong here, any suggestions ? Is there any way to register it in XML for SmartTable ? I would like not to switch to sap.m.table in the XML view but leave it as it is. Would appreciate your help Gurus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because the items are "**inactive**". Check document [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#attachItemPress)

> >
>   attachItemPress(oData?, fnFunction, oListener?): sap.m.ListBase
>   Attaches event handler fnFunction to the itemPress event of this sap.m.ListBase.
>   When called, the context of the event handler (its this) will be bound to oListener if specified, otherwise it will be bound to this sap.m.ListBase itself.
>
> >
>   Fires when an item is pressed unless the item's type property is **Inactive**.

Please use the below code and `attachDataReceived` of `SmartTable` is working.

```
var fnItemPress = function(){alert("press")};   
tTable.attachDataReceived(function(){
    var aItems = oTable.getItems();
    if(aItems.length === 0 ) return;
    $.each(aItems, function(oIndex, oItem) {
        oItem.detachPress(fnItemPress);
        oItem.setType("Active");
        oItem.attachPress(fnItemPress);
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: What about detaching this event? Otherwice there will be as many attached events as the "updateFinished" events fired on the table, which will lead to multiple event triggerings :)

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych I think you are right about this. I have changed my code. Now it is working even the table is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that no chance to do that without the table definition in XML. But I guess you can omit "columns" aggregation definition and in "items" include only "ColumnListItem" with the needed event handler (without "cells"). Smart Table should automatically inject neeeded columns/cells.

Comment: I have tried to put the  <Table><items><ColumnListItem press="onItemPress"/>  (...) but did not help.

Comment: what did you exactly try?

Comment: i put between smarttable tags; <Table><items><ColumnListItem press="onItemPress"/></items></table>

Comment: Do you use (LineItem) annotations for smart table?

Comment: Both [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3697995) 
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342554/ui5-sap-m-table-itempress-event)
it says that you might need to set the type property of ColumnListItem:
Either “<ColumnListItem type="Navigation>...</ColumnListItem>”
or “<ColumnListItem type="Active">...</ColumnListItem>”.

Does this work?

Comment: Did not work. Thanks for help though, the solution from Allen works.